# Guard dogs: where do they come from?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

How come some people seem to have dogs always, is there a time where it is automatically there? Maybe at a certain level or is it always a Kill streak?

Comment: Guard dogs are kill streaks, and for some annoying reason they never expire unless killed

Answer (score 4):

The [Guard Dog](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Guard_Dog) is a possible [point-streak reward](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Strike_Chain) for acquiring 5 points (or 4 with the hardline perk). Once activated, the dog remains active until either the dog or owner are killed.

Answer (score 1):

The Guard Dog is a point-streak reward that you get upon reaching 5 points. You do not automatically  receive a permanent one for reaching a certain level or rank. 
In **normal respawn** gamemodes such as Team Deathmatch, Domination and Blitz the dog will remain alive until someone kills it, the round ends, or the game ends. Upon killing the owner that has a Guard Dog, the Dog will attempt to chase and get revenge on the player that killed its owner. If it succeeds, it will path its way back to the owner killing anyone it crosses.
In **non-normal respawn** gamemodes such as Search & Rescue, Search & Rescue and Reinforce. The dog will also remain alive until someone kills it, the round ends, or the game ends. **However,** when the owner dies, the Guard Dog dies immediately with the owner. 
Because of this you are less likely to see many guard dogs in the non-normal respawn gamemodes. Hope this helps.